# Algorithm to compute automorphism group of a finite group

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, algorithms, computer-algebra, computational-group-theory

Is there an algorithm to compute automorphism group of a finite group?

GAP has a function to do this, but while perusing their GitHub repo, I could not find an implementation. I'm struggling to find anything else related to this online. Any clues?

Note: I am trying to write my own group theory library (for fun and learning). So I need an actual algorithm.

Comment: Do you mean "of a finite group"? or "of a group given by a finite presentation"? as such "group" the question makes little sense.

Comment: Good point - I meant of a finite group.

Comment: Yes, there is an algorithm: Run through all permutations of G and check for homomorphisms. Presumably you mean an efficient algorithm?

Comment: Find a generating set for $G$ of size at most $\log_2|G|$ try all possible images of the generators in the group and check which of these extends to an isomorphism. This has complexity something like $|G|^{O(\log |G|)}$, and there is no known algorithm that has been proved to have better theoretical complexity. It is an open problem whether it can be done in time polynomial in $|G|$. I could say a lot more about this, but not without going into a lot of technical and theoretical detail. Incidentally, what input for your algorithm do you envisage? How is the group to be input?

Comment: @DerekHolt Thank you, this is helpful. My idea at the moment was basically that, but I wanted to optimize it, or find something better. I am wondering if some kind of backtracking with smart pruning is helpful?

Comment: @DerekHolt The group is input as a group of elements, and there is an abstract compose function. You can just assume it is a Cayley table.

Comment: There are lots of obvious optimizations. For example you only need to try images in which the orders are the same as those of the generators. The problem with input by Cayley table is that is restricts the order of groups that you process too much for the sort of computations that we want to in practice. generally we work with groups of permutations or matrices, and input groups by generating sets.

Comment: @DerekHolt Unfortunately that is the only optimization I could come up with. I am certainly missing a lot of the ideas I need to do this right. Where should I look?

Comment: @JerryHalisberry see also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/947945/ for finding where certain things are implemented in GAP.